# leap-motion for people affected by neurodegenerative diseases

Tags: leap-motion

I'm new to this type of device and i want to know if it's possible to use the device like a simple movement detector so people with neurodegenerative diseases can use pc also with a low mobility. 
I'm thinking to develop simple app to allow access for simple task like reading or manage the music play.

And if it's possible can i detect more than the simple rotate left and right and the 4 direction movement.
Thank for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The Leap Motion API gives you finger tip positions, pointing direction and velocity in 3 dimensions. It gives you hand position, direction, and velocity, as well as the normal vector to the hand plane -- with the direction and normal vectors together, you know the orientation of the hand. There are also a few builtin gestures, like swipe and taps.

Comment: Thanks.
I hope it's possible to use it also with motion disease. Thanks